# How do linux file descriptor limits work?

Tags: linux, sockets, file, file-descriptor

I was told that my server refused to accept client network connections at a specific port could be due to the lack of file descriptors. I looked up what this is all about and read about it here:  http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html

So I tested my system and I got this:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1088    0   331287
```

What does this mean?

The second column actually stays at 0 even after I shutdown my server, it even stays at 0 even right after a boot!

Comment: Please see http://serverfault.com/questions/190435/how-to-increase-open-files-limit-for-process-from-1024-to-10240 -

Comment: Do you have any new results regarding your problem? Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to look at /proc/sys/fs/file-max instead

From recent linux/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt:

> file-max & file-nr:

> The kernel allocates file handles dynamically, but as yet it
> doesn't free them again.

> The value in file-max denotes the maximum number of file-
> handles that the Linux kernel will allocate. When you get lots
> of error messages about running out of file handles, you might
> want to increase this limit.

> Historically, the three values in file-nr denoted the number of
> allocated file handles, the number of allocated but unused file
> handles, and the maximum number of file handles. Linux 2.6 always
> reports 0 as the number of free file handles -- this is not an
> error, it just means that the number of allocated file handles
> exactly matches the number of used file handles.

> Attempts to allocate more file descriptors than file-max are
> reported with printk, look for "VFS: file-max limit 
> reached".

EDIT: the underlying error is probably not the system running out of global filedescriptors, but just your process.  It seems likely that the problem is the [maximum size limit of select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991223/how-does-linux-file-descriptor-limits-work/3991261#3991261).

Answer (score 5):

It does not look like you are hitting the system file desriptor limit. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991223/how-does-linux-file-descriptor-limits-work/3991315#3991315).

Perhaps your server process uses `select` and is thus limited to 1024 descriptors? If you switch to another mechanism, e.g. `poll` you will not be limited to 1024 descriptors anymore.

`select()` works with `fd_set`s

[This is from the POSIX documentation of select.h:](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/select.h.html)

> The following shall be defined as a macro:
>
> FD_SETSIZE
>
> ```
> Maximum number of file descriptors in an fd_set structure.
> ```

Try to find or output `FD_SETSIZE` on your system.

If you find FD_SETSIZE is too low for you, I would rather try to move away from `select` than trying to increase `FD_SETSIZE` which is typically harder.

Comment: select is limited by 1024 descriptors? Can you explain further?

Comment: has nothing to do with FD_SETSIZE

Comment: @unbeli I've seen hitting FD_SETSIZE in servers using select time and again. Please explain what happens to erotsppa in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting from accept() under these circumstances? Check errno and report it accordingly.

According to the man page, accept() will give EMFILE or ENFILE if the per-process or overall file descriptor limit has been reached, it would be helpful to know which (or if there was something else).

There is a per-process file descriptor limit which is often set to 1024 - but can easily be increased.