# Failed to write session data (memcache)

Tags: php, memcached

I'm noticing an ***intermittent*** issue with our Memcached session handler. The error that occurs is:

> Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcache). Please verify that
>   the current setting of session.save_path is correct.

Notes:

- It seems to be an intermittent issue that occurs 5 or 6 times a day to various users.
- Memcached is not localhost. i.e. It's on a different server than the web server.
- I'm using the Memcache extension (as opposed to the MemcacheD extension).
- I'm using the tcp prefix. If you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112319/failed-to-write-session-data-php-and-memcached), you'll see that the "fix" was to put tcp:// a prefix if you're using the Memcache extension.

My php.ini settings:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://64.233.191.255:11211"
```

Note that I've also used:

```
session.save_path = "tcp://64.233.191.255:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
```

But it doesn't seem to matter.

Checked the memcached.log file, where I found the following error:

> Failed to write, and not due to blocking: Connection reset by peer.

Note: This particular error occurs at least once, at the same time (01:07AM), everyday. It will then occur sporadically throughout the day.

Comment: Have you checke log files of the memcache server at the times where the errors appeared in logs of web server? looks like a connection problem. Maybe because of load peek?

Comment: I would go for network issues. Some cron jobs on memcache machine? Temporary high network load?

Comment: @PawełSpychalski Yep. There are cron jobs on the machine. We have a DB backup running at midnight. However, the machine has a lot of cores and it regularly sees loads of 4.00+ 1:09AM would be very low peak.

Comment: @WayneWhitty still, something is happening at 1:09AM what is causing those network problems. Are you sure none of crons is not restarting memcache or doing smth nasty?

Comment: what is the timeout setting for your server on tcp level? maybe it's just not the memcache server itself but a script that runs longer as expected due to slow db responses and times out. Like at a point, where you are waiting for a db reply and writing that to your memcache afterwards, but the connection already timed out at this point

Comment: Which `memcache` version are you using ?

Comment: @WayneWhitty did you sort this out? I'm also experience the similar issue and curious about solution

Comment: @Eugene Unfortunately, I couldn't "fix" the issue. Thankfully, it only seems to occur after midnight, when nobody is using the app. Chris' answer below makes the most sense to me, seeing as we are carrying out a heavy database backup at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're [running out of filehandles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991223/how-does-linux-file-descriptor-limits-work)? Perhaps the backups make your machine swap, resulting in slower responses, meaning more concurrent connections to the memcached process resulting in a stampeding hurd.